# Is the Uniform family of Distributions dominated by the Lebesgue Measure?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

The answer to this question should be fairly easy, but I can not just see it.

I want to say something like: let us consider a measure $P_{\theta}\in\mathcal{P}$ where $\mathcal{P}=\left\{P_{\theta}:\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\lambda}=I_{(\theta-0.5,\theta+0.5)}(x) \right\}$, that is, the family of uniform distributions in $(\theta-0.5,\theta+0.5)$, where  $\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\lambda}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $P_{\theta}$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

That is, I am assuming $\mathcal{P}$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure and the Radon- Nikodym derivative of $P_{\theta}$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\lambda}=I_{(\theta-0.5,\theta+0.5)}(x)
\end{equation}

However, if I want to prove that $\mathcal{P}$ is not an exponential family, one way to prove it is to show that there does not exist a dominating measure that results in such a Radon-Nikodym derivative.

The argument is as follows. If there exists such a measure, let us say $\nu$, with  Radon-Nykodim derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\nu}=I_{(\theta-0.5,\theta+0.5)}(x)
\end{equation}

then for each $t\geq 0$ there is a $\theta<t-0.5$ such that $P_\theta[[t,\infty)]=0$, which, along with the existence of the previous Radon-Nikodym derivative implies $\nu[[t,\infty)]=0$, which implies that $\nu[[0,\infty)]=0$. Following a symmetric argument, $\nu[(-\infty,0]]=0$ and then $\nu=0$.

Therefore, there is no such a measure $\nu$ that gives us the Radon-Nykodim derivative, which is requirement for the exponential family.

I am sure I am missing something.

Any hints?

Comment: Isn't the implication the other way around, i.e. $\nu[t,\infty) = 0 \implies P_\theta[t,\infty) = 0$?

Comment: I've only ever seen a Uniform distribution on an interval $(a,b)$ defined via the density 
$f := \frac{1}{b-a}I_{(a,b)}$:
$$
  P(A) = \int_A f(x) d\lambda(x)
$$
and so, by definition, $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\lambda$ and has the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$. Are you starting from a different definition?

Comment: @Rookatu This is a particular case of $U(a,b)$, but the result is similar for the general case as well.

Comment: Dear @Rookatu, you are right. The condition to show that a family  is exponential, that is $\frac{dP_\theta}{d\lambda}=\exp\{\eta(\theta)T(x)-\zeta(\theta)\}h(x)$ is that there exists a measure $\nu$ such that $\frac{dP_\theta}{d\nu}=\exp\{\eta(\theta)T(x)-\zeta(\theta)\}>0 \forall x \forall \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in the post is not the question in the title. The answer to the question in the title is "yes, obviously" since for every $\theta$, $P_\theta\ll\lambda$ by definition. The answer to the question in the post is "no, $\mathcal P$ is not an exponential family". To see this, recall that the support of every measure in an exponential family does not depend on the measure, here $[h\ne0]$ should be independent of $\theta$.

But $P_0((1/2,1))=0$ while $P_1((1/2,1))\ne0$ hence $\mathcal P$ is not an exponential family. In fact, for every $t\ne s$, $\{P_t,P_s\}$ is not an exponential family.

Comment: Dear @Did, You are right. I just got confused because the argument to show that this family is not exponential suggests that no measure dominates the uniform family. However, after a second thought, the requirement to be exponential is that there exists a nonzero measure such that $\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\nu}=exp\{\eta(\theta)T(x)-\zeta(\theta)\}\forall x \forall\theta$, which becomes the condition you mention. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This is not the condition, you missed a factor $h(x)$ in the RHS.